# Horizontal auto-scroll of text in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, textblock, autoscroll

I want to have a fixed-width `TextBlock` that has long, unbroken, horizontal text, and am looking for a good approach to allow all the text to be read by the user. I want something more sophisticated than just putting the control inside a `ScrollViewer`.

**First (ideal) option** is to be able to hover the mouse over the `TextBlock` and if the mouse is right of center for example, it would scroll to the right (with increasing speed the further you move from the center). I guess this is do-able, by handling MouseEnter / MouseOver events on the TextBlock, figuring out where the cursor is within the TextBlock, and enabling some marquee/animation as appropriate. I'm looking for approaches on how to do this, particularly as I have little experience with animation in WPF. Would like to figure out the detail myself but struggling to get started.

**Second option** would be to have a `RepeatButton` on either side of the text, and when you hover over that, it scrolls the text.

An initial attempt:

```
<RepeatButton ClickMode="Hover"
              Command="{x:Static ComponentCommands.MoveLeft}"
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TextAutoScroller}"
              Content="Go left" />

<ScrollViewer x:Name="TextAutoScroller" Grid.Column="1"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.&#x0d;&#x0a;The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.&#x0d;&#x0a;The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." />
</ScrollViewer>

<RepeatButton Grid.Column="2"
              ClickMode="Hover"
              Command="{x:Static ComponentCommands.ScrollPageRight}"
              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TextAutoScroller}"
              Content="Go right" />
```

The problem with this is that both `RepeatButton` controls are disabled - seems that neither `MoveLeft` or `ScrollPageRight` are supported, but `ScollPageDown` (no good for my horizontal scenario) works ok?

Any tips or suggestions on either option would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tooltip is what I have right now, but would like to experiment with this auto-scrolling concept.

Comment: Just my opinion but auto scroll doesn't sound great to me. I wouldn't want my display being mucked with simply by moving my mouse around.

Comment: I agree that I would not like a mouse enter moving text.  You do know arrow right and left will scroll.  You might be able to call those keys to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Fair comment, I'm used to seeing similar behavior in Flash apps on the web but not necessarily for scrolling text. Even if you forget about the mouseover on the TextBlock doing anything though, I'm also struggling with the RepeatButton like I said - any ideas on that?

Comment: To to call the right and left arrow keys in code to scroll the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution for the repeatable button version would be to just scroll the scrollviewer incrementally.

```
private void scrollLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset - 10);
}

private void scrollRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset + 10);
}
```

The above assumes your text is wrapped in a scrollviewer named sv, with two repeatbuttons.

If you want to speed up the longer you've held it in:

```
    private int offset = 1;
    private int maxOffset = 50;

    private void scrollLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset - offset);
        offset += offset < maxOffset ? 1 : 0;
    }

    private void scrollRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset + offset);
        offset += offset < maxOffset ? 1 : 0;
    }

    private void scrollRight_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        offset = 1;
    }
```

I would also weigh in and suggest not using the ClickMode="Hover"... Users are more accustomed to clicking buttons. Just my two cents.